# Shadow of Apple's Environment-Sheets - in CSS3?

Tags: css

Is it possible to create shadows like the shadow of Apple's environment-information sheets with CSS3?

[image: example image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://images.apple.com/environment/images/footprint_graph20100920.jpg))</sub>

The solution doesn't have to be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Did you check and see how Apple was doing it on their webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See [this blog post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/) and [the demo page](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/) for how it's done

Answer (score 2):

Check out the demo on this site:

http://lab.galengidman.com/css3stickynote/

They do something really similar in pure CSS with a bunch of `:before` and `:after` voodoo.

Here is the particular code they use for the shadow effects:

```
#stickynote:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:90%;
    height:20%;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:3px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:-1;
}

#stickynote:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:90%;
    height:20%;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom:3px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:-1;
}
```